# Tool to find a windows PID by aiming at it

Tags: windows, debugging, pid

For debugging purposes there once was a small utility which could be used to aim at GUI window to identify its PID.

I am aware that `process explorer` provides this functionality, however it has slow startup time and often crashes on my Windows Server 2012 R2 machine.

I just can't remeber the name of the tool. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the tools name was `winspy++`? You can aim on the target window and get all informations about that window